# How to convert this Linux makefile to Windows makefile?

Tags: linux, windows, makefile

I don't know a lot of things about makefiles. This makefile written in Linux and it works on Linux. Also I don't know which Linux distrubition. I am using Windows 10. I need a Windows makefile that does the same thing with this Linux makefile. (folder locations and names are same)

```
ASM=nasm
CC=gcc

SRC_DIR=src
TOOLS_DIR=tools
BUILD_DIR=build

.PHONY: all floppy_image kernel bootloader clean always tools_fat

all: floppy_image tools_fat

#
# Floppy image
#
floppy_image: $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: bootloader kernel
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
    mkfs.fat -F 12 -n "NBOS" $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin of=$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img conv=notrunc
    mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"
    mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img test.txt "::test.txt"

#
# Bootloader
#
bootloader: $(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin: always
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/bootloader/boot.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin

#
# Kernel
#
kernel: $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin: always
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/kernel/main.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin

#
# Tools
#
tools_fat: $(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat
$(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat: always $(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/tools
    $(CC) -g -o $(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat $(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c

#
# Always
#
always:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

#
# Clean
#
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

I said to ChatGPT to convert this file. But ChatGPT couldn't. I am expecting new converted makefile should make same things with Linux makefile.

Also I looked other questions about makefiles. But still I can't understand how to write it in makefile. I don't know a lot of things about makefiles.

Comment: Why not install a Linux-like environment on your Windows system, and just use that? For example [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)? Or perhaps a full virtual machine? Maybe even it's enough with [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org) and MinGW?

Comment: SO is not a way to get free gig programming.  If you have a specific question about a specific issue, post the change you tried and the error you got and we can try to help.  Looking at this makefile the short answer to your question is "you can't do it".  The UNIX tools being used here are to create a bootloader image from a kernel.  There are no straightforward tools to do that on Windows that I'm aware of (but, I don't do much Windows).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you are trying to accomplish and why, specifically why you want/need to do this under Windows? This `Makefile` is exceedingly specific to Linux.